# how to expand UITextview automatically based on displaying string in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitextview

I have two textViews whose data gets populated dynamically. I want to resize the height of the textview once the data is populated so that I don't see a vertical scroll nor the text gets clipped. I want to do this task programmatically.

```
tViewhobbies=[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 
                                                         330, 
                                                         300, 
                                                         strSize.height+20)];
tViewhobbies.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];            
tViewhobbies.layer.cornerRadius=5;            
[tViewhobbies setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];            
tViewhobbies.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];            
tViewhobbies.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.662745 
                                             green:0.662745 
                                              blue:0.662745 
                                             alpha:0.5];
tViewhobbies.delegate=self;            
tViewhobbies.scrollEnabled=YES;            
[scrollView addSubview:tViewhobbies];    

lblInterests = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 
                                                        410, 
                                                        300, 
                                                        strSize.height+0)];

lblInterests.text=@"Interests";       
lblInterests.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16.0];            
lblInterests.textColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:153.0f/255.0f 
                                       green:153.0f/255.0f 
                                        blue:153.0f/255.0f 
                                       alpha:1];            
[scrollView addSubview:lblInterests];            

tViewInterests=[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 
                                                           430, 
                                                           300, 
                                                           strSize.height+30)];

tViewInterests.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];            
tViewInterests.layer.cornerRadius=5;            
[tViewInterests setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];            
tViewInterests.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0];            
tViewInterests.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:0.662745 
                                               green:0.662745 
                                                blue:0.662745 
                                               alpha:0.5];
tViewInterests.delegate=self;            
tViewInterests.scrollEnabled=YES;            
[scrollView addSubview:tViewInterests];
```

Comment: Have you try `[txtvw sizeToFit]` ?

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
NSDictionary *attributes = @{NSFontAttributeName: [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]};
CGRect rect = 
   [aTextView.text boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(300, MAXFLOAT)
                                options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                             attributes:attributes
                                context:nil];
aTextView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0,300, rect.size.height);
```

Comment: it's a constant defined in math.h, you don't need to assign a value to it.

Answer (score 0):

```
[textview sizeToFit];
[textview.textContainer setSize:textview.frame.size];
```

in iOS 7 u may use:

```
[UITEXTVIEW sizeToFit];
[UITEXTVIEW layoutIfNeeded];
```

if Problem still exists, give update